# After I have successfully downloaded a module using pip in vs code and try to use said module i get the error message "no module named [module]"

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

There is no error when I download the module using pip and I can even see the file location where the module is installed but it still says that it is not installed. Additionally a few modules like numpy do work and are in the same folder as the ones that do.

a specific example of this is with opencv-python

after installing the module using pip

```
pip install opencv-python
```

and then trying to use the module with

```
import cv2
```

I get the error message

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'
PS C:\users\cc\appdata\local\packages\pythonsoftwarefoundation.python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\localcache\local-packages\python311\site-p> & C:/Users/cc/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python3alcache11/python.exe c:/Users/cc/OneDrive/Documents/fedg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\cc\OneDrive\Documents\fedg", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
    ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Comment: find out in which specific python interpreter you installed the module

Comment: have you used virtualenv or any other similar tool? If yes have you configured it the VSCode?

Comment: You may need to do "pip install --user opencv-python" depending on how your environment is set up.

Comment: @rioV8 Python 3.11.3

Comment: does it work if you open a 3.11.3 REPL by executing the python interpreter from the terminal

Comment: @Swaroop I believe I have but could you explain what you mean in case I have some misconception/ made a mistake

Comment: @rioV8 didnt work in replit it said its missing the file "config.py"

Comment: why do you need `config.py` to start a REPL or to execute `import cv2`

Comment: If you are using any of the virtualenv tools, then that interpreter should be active in your vscode. Which virtual environment tool are you using??

Comment: @rioV8 it specifically said "raise ImportError('OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: {}. Check OpenCV installation.'.format(fnames))
ImportError: OpenCV loader: missing configuration file: ['config.py']. Check OpenCV installation"

Comment: then first make sure you use python 3.11.3 in VSC by selecting the correct `Python interpreter` (a command)

Comment: @swaroop I remember seeing using a virtual environment as a soution which I tried but do not remember the details of but currently I am not using any virtual environments

Comment: Can you tell me the output of `pip show opencv-python` ?

Comment: @Swaroop 
Name: opencv-python
Version: 4.8.0.76
Summary: Wrapper package for OpenCV python bindings.
Home-page: https://github.com/opencv/opencv-python
Author:
Author-email:
License: Apache 2.0
Location: C:\Users\cc\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python311\site-packages
Requires: numpy, numpy, numpy, numpy, numpy
Required-by:

Comment: and VSCode config?

Comment: @Swaroop How would I access that?

Comment: follow guidelines on https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments to setup the environment.